# Mockito com NativeQuery

Tags: java, mockito

preciso testar um metodo que usa native query. Porém na linha

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(strQuery, Projeto.class);
```

Não se atribui valor nenhum a q e ele fica nulo.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue metodo que quero testar (que está na classe  ProjetoServiceImpl) :

```
@Override
public  Page<Projeto> buscaAtestadosComFiltro(String[] filtros, PageRequest pageRequest) {
    String strQuery = montaQueryAtestadoComFiltro(filtros);
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(strQuery, Projeto.class);
    Page<Projeto> result = new PageImpl<Projeto>(q.getResultList());
    return result;
}
```

e minha classe de teste:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ProjetoServiceImplTest {

  Projeto projeto1;

  @Mock
  private EntityManager manager;

  @InjectMocks
  private ProjetoServiceImpl projImpl = new ProjetoServiceImpl();

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    projeto1 = new Projeto();
    projeto1.setId(1L);
 }

 @Test
public void testaBuscaAtestadosComFiltro() {
    List<Projeto> projetos = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
    projetos.add(projeto1);

    Query query = mock(Query.class);

    Mockito.when(manager.createNativeQuery("java",Projeto.class)).thenReturn(query);
    Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(projetos);

    String[] filtros = new String[] {"java"};
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 12,Direction.valueOf("DESC"), "id");

    Page<Projeto> result = projImpl.buscaAtestadosComFiltro(filtros, pageRequest);
    assertNotNull(result);

}
```

Comment: Já tentou `manager.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(Projeto.class))`?

Comment: eele nem aceita o segundo argumento

Comment: Então Já tentou `manager.createNativeQuery(Mockito.anyString(), Projeto.class)`?